# How to animate a second object in Vidle for python

Tags: python

Well this is more of practice work than homework, but this code in VIDLE python(that comes as a sample code) is abouta ball bouncing. I want to add another ball but it doesnt bounce like the rest. Can some one help me make it work? and or add in another object? and any tips to make it fancy.....oh and can some one please be a life saver and tell me how to make it explode. no sound(although sound would be nice) just explosion.
here is the code:

```
from visual import *

floor = box(length=10, height=2, width=10, color=color.white)

ball = box(length=2, height=2, width=2, pos=(0,4,0), color=color.yellow)
ball.velocity = vector(0,8,0)

ball2 = sphere(length=2, height=2, width=2, pos=(2,4,2), color=color.cyan,     material=materials.wood)
ball2.velocity = vector(1,8,1)
dt = 0.04
dt2 = 0.01

while 1:
 rate(100)
 ball.pos = ball.pos + ball.velocity*dt
 if ball.y < 1:
    ball.velocity.y = -ball.velocity.y
 else:
    ball.velocity.y = ball.velocity.y - 9.8*dt

while 1:
 rate(100)
 ball2.pos = ball2.pos + ball2.velocity*dt2
 if ball2.y < 1:
    ball2.velocity.y = -ball2.velocity.y
 else:        
    ball2.velocity.y = ball2.velocity.y - 9.8*dt2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is "stuck" in the first `while 1:` loop.

Have a look at your code and ask yourself "when will this code be run"? about the second while loop.

The answer is "never", because it keeps going around the first loop.

You need to have only one loop handling both balls, instead of one loop for one ball then another loop for another one.

```
while 1:
 rate(100)
 ball.pos = ball.pos + ball.velocity*dt
 if ball.y < 1:
    ball.velocity.y = -ball.velocity.y
 else:
    ball.velocity.y = ball.velocity.y - 9.8*dt

 ball2.pos = ball2.pos + ball2.velocity*dt2
 if ball2.y < 1:
    ball2.velocity.y = -ball2.velocity.y
 else:        
    ball2.velocity.y = ball2.velocity.y - 9.8*dt2
```

---

> and can some one please be a life saver and tell me how to make it explode

You only get one question per question on Stack Overflow ;)

About exploding: you need to get a lot more familiar with the basics of python (like how loops work) before you can do an explosion.

Comment: heres the thing, I am familiar with loops, it's just that this whole modeling thing is new to me and i have this other hw for the same class on the  side that literally has the whole class confused. I jsut thought it'd be fun to learn this. But could you tlel me where to start with the explosion?

Comment: You need to create all the exploding pieces then animate them moving apart and disappearing.  In the VPython palette, this might be best achieved with red dots ("points") that you move fast outwards from the location of the ball, then remove...  that's just one way to try...

Comment: You're welcome.  At StackOverflow, the way to express your thanks is to upvote the answer, and also accept it (if it is the right answer for you) by clicking the tick.